# Activate window when hovering Adobe app on second monitor

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-indesign, windows

I have a two monitor setup. I run Photoshop maximized on screen 1 and InDesign maximized on screen 2.
When I copy from indesign to photoshop, I have to activate the photoshop window with the first click, othervise i paste the content back to indesign, in spite of hovering the photoshop window on screen 1.
I tried multiple software or the windows function "activate window by hover", but it only works on windows folders, it does not work on adobe apps.
Do you have / use any solution?
Thanks

**What I do:**
Copy image by ctrl+c in indesign on monitor 2, hover mouse over photoshop on monitor 1, hit ctrl+v

**What happens:**
Image is pasted into indesign, because photoshop window wasn´t activated

**What I have to do to make it work:**
Copy image by ctrl+c in indesign on monitor 2, hover mouse over photoshop on monitor 1, click into the photoshop window, hit ctrl+v

**How it should work / What I want:**
Copy image by ctrl+c in indesign on monitor 2, hover mouse over photoshop on monitor 1, hit ctrl+v, image is pasted into photoshop without need of additional mouseclick.

Comment: No such functionality log a feature request.

Comment: Adobe programs are made in that way that you have to activate them to use them.

Comment: I can confirm that the "activate windows by hover" usability feature in Win10 doesn't work with any Adobe CC applications I've tested, although it does work with many other non-Adobe applications.  This is ultimately something you'd need to take up with Adobe I think. Clearly it's something they have not implemented either for some unknown reason, or because they have simply chosen to ignore it.

Comment: It seems that this isn't possible. I'm not familiar with working on multiple monitors. Is it possible to just press *Alt+Tab* to switch to Photoshop? That could be a solution. Another thing. I'm not saying that I *never* copy an image from InDesign to Photoshop, but it's only under very rare circumstances. Why do you need to do this so often that one extra click is annoying? Are you editing the image and then copying it back? In that case it would be easier to work with placed images.

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue with Windows, not Adobe. Windows never activates a window when you hover it. Luckily there's an easy fix:

1. Go to *Control Panel* > *Ease of Access* >  *Ease of Access Center* > *Make the mouse easier to use*
2. Select *Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse*

Done!

Mind you this activates this behaviour for *all* windows.

Comment: Hmm . . . in Windows 10, this fix doesn't seem to work with any Adobe applications at all, so it would seem Adobe hasn't implemented it. Perhaps they chose not to, or just ignored this usability feature. However it does work with other applications such as GIMP, Inkscape, LibreOffice, Firefox, Chrome, and Scribus.  Naughty Adobe!!

Comment: Haven't tested with Adobe programs to be honest :)

Comment: Not working for Adobe